# Submit a view instead of redirect to another view

Tags: php, joomla-3.4, form, redirect

I have 2 views namely `students` and `student`.  The `students` view will list all the students and `student` view is to show the details of the student.  These 2 views are accessible for all staffs in the school to view their students.

Currently I using an anchor link in the `students` view by passing the `student_id` as one of the argument in href to the `student` view.  The problem here is if the staff simply goes to the URL and changes the `student_id` to some other number then the staff able to view the other student details.

I want to stop this in a easier way instead of checking again on the database whether the particular student reports to the logged in staff.

I thought of something to do with Joomla `form.token` and submit the first view while clicking the student name and the next view can validate the token and show the full details.

I am not sure whether it makes sense but I thought this will make my life easier instead of writing several validations.

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question... I should have spend some time in google before asking my question.

Joomla supports CSRF anti-spoofing and it is explained in [How_to_add_CSRF_anti-spoofing_to_forms](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_add_CSRF_anti-spoofing_to_forms)

Since I am using GET method I should use the below while forming the HRF

```
<?php 
echo JRoute::_( 'index.php?option=com_example&controller=object1&task=save&'. JSession::getFormToken() .'=1' ); 
?>
```

and in the other page check as below

```
JSession::checkToken( 'get' ) or die( 'Invalid Token' );
```